# Listen to the scroll event of primeng data table

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, primeng-datatable

How to listen to the scroll event of primeng data table which has fixed header. If no event available, how to add a custom event. Following is the data table properties:

```
<p-dataTable #dt [value]="manualProcessGridData" 
                                    [(selection)]="selectedRows" 
                                    [(rows)]="rowsCountPerPage" 
                                    [paginator]="true"
                                    [pageLinks]="3" 
                                    [rowsPerPageOptions]="[5,10,20]" 
                                    [lazy]="true" 
                                    (onLazyLoad)="loadData($event,false,'')" 
                                    [(totalRecords)]="totalRecords"
                                    sortField="totalProcessingTime" 
                                    sortOrder="1" scrollable="true" 
                                    [scrollHeight]="viewHeight">
```

Comment: try like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46292509/unable-to-use-primeng-p-datatable-virtual-scroll-lazy-load/46294970#46294970